# Cloudsim/Softlayer: password? emacs?

Tags: cloudsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

1. How do I scp stuff to the field computer: What is the password for the user ubuntu?
2. Could emacs be part of the standard installation?

Thanks,
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3019/cloudsim/softlayer:-password?-emacs?/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

1. There's no password for the ubuntu user; we're using SSH keys (once you're on the machine, the ubuntu user has password-less sudo access).  Each machine's `.zip` file contains a `.pem` file that is the private SSH key for that machine.  There's an [example command-line](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/CloudSim/VRCUserGuide#How_to_install_custom_worlds_for_testing) in the VRC User Guide for scping files to the Simulation machine.  The same process can be used for the other machines, swapping key file name and IP address as needed.
2. Sure, we can add emacs to the provisioning.  This won't be the only such request, so I've opened a [ticket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/cloudsim/issue/116/add-packages-to-provisioning-of) to track them.  Feel free to add more requested packages there.  To avoid disruption during Practice, we won't be doing any installations for you, so you'll need to add extra stuff yourself.  The extra packages will come installed by default when the machines get reloaded for Competition.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0